# How to skip certain jobs which are imported from another repository in Gitlab

Tags: gitlab-ci, pipeline, cicd

In my .gitlab-ci.yml I have the following:

```
include:
  - project: 'some/project/in-gitlab'
    file:
      - '/some/file.yml'
```

In `some/project/in-gitlab/some/file.yml` lets say it has 4 stages:

```
stages:
 - job1
 - job2
 - job3
 - job4
```

I want to run only `job1` and `job2` in my pipeline. How to run only `job1` and `job2` which are inherited from `some/project/in-gitlab/some/file.yml`?

Comment: do you want to skip jobs or all jobs in the particular stages you have mentioned.

Comment: No not all jobs. I want to skip only lets say job2 and job4 for example. But job1 and job3 should run.

Answer (score 0):

```yaml
include:
  - project: 'some/project/in-gitlab'
    file:
      - '/some/file.yml'

stages:
 - job1
 - job2
 - job3
 - job4

job2:
 rules:
 - when: never

job4:
 rules:
   - when: never
```

This will ensure `job2` and `job4` doesn't run.

But I would suggest you split the jobs into different files and just include the ones which are needed.